# Can origami math solve polynomial equations of degree greater than 3?

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, roots, geometric-construction, origami

I heard that straight edge + compass can solve up to quadratic equations. I've also heard the Origami/Paper-folding can solve cubic equations. But can it solve higher-degree polynomial equations (e.g. quartic, quintic) in general? If not, is there a geometric construction framework that could solve these higher degree polynomial equations?

My intuition says that degree 5 and higher can't be solved because of the Abel-Ruffini theorem proving that no general formula exists for degree-5 and higher polynomial equations that only involves arithmetic and radicals.

Comment: Notably, Mathologer published a video touching on this very topic a few days ago -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUC-8P0zXe8. He did say cubics were possible, which he showed with an example, but I forget if he touched on if that method generalized even higher up.